# How to explain perpetual earthquake magnitude at least 5 on Richter scale?

Tags: science-based, apocalypse, earth, natural-disasters

I need an event man-made or not on Earth that can generate consistent earthquake that never grow weak, sky is the limit meaning any astronomical events will be ruled out. My story can take place during any period in history(not prehistory) up to 100 years from now, the mechanism/principle behind it must sound accurate and believable by the scientific community.

Comment: Hi user6760. I think science-based is a reasonable tag to add here, and earth because this is about the Earth. Feel free to roll back if you disagree strongly.

Comment: How far should the earthquake be felt?  Are we talking the radius of my house, a city,...?  If you give us a hint as to what kind of devastation, feeling etc. you'd like, that might affect the best answer.  Just for reference, a Richter 5 isn't particularly dangerous (I know that you might not be looking for mass destruction, just wanted to say heads up).

Comment: @Mikey: I can also accept a real life simulation but it will inevitably stop due to power shortage or maintenance.

Comment: I don't think your _"sky is the limit"_ approach can work. The only things I can imagine generating a _semiperpetual_ (constant for years/decades/centuries) earthquake are tidal forces, and you need a very huge stellar object orbiting the Earth on a quite close orbit. That could be another moon made of heavy metals or transuranic elements.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the tide strength.  This could be done by bringing a micro black hole (either one that hasn't evaporated since the big bang or an artificial one) and dropping it into the moon.  If you significantly increase the moon's mass (and speed so that it doesn't spiral in) then it will cause the crust to bulge more than it currently does, adding energy to and increasing the tectonic plate movement. (Note: the mass increase is simply due to the addition of the black hole mass, not the moon getting eaten by the black hole. The suggestion of dropping it into the moon was simply to prevent unpredictable multiple body issues. )

Increase the lubrication of the plates by some chemical or microbial action developing along the fault lines. This could be, for example, a microbe engineered to dissolve various rocks to assist mining operations which escapes confinement.

Weaponised dark matter.  WIMPS (weakly interacting massive particles) heating the core, causing magma melts,  pushing plates apart. Magma blooms (large melts) are thought to have caused Pangaea to break apart.  Judicial use may cause volcanic activity on one side and earthquakes on the other side of a tectonic plate.

Comment: No astronomical event "horizon" please

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/129/

Comment: Ok, didn't realize the sky limit. But the next two can be Earth based. However, the amount of energy required to drive such earthquakes is ginormous. The microbe idea uses the current energy of the fault lines so will peter out after a few years.

Answer (score 0):

If the earthquake doesn't need a 'beginning' the you could just say that it has always been there. I mean that as in the tectonic plates that cause most earthquakes just move faster and have created a never-ending cycle of vibration between the plates. They could be moving faster due the the sub-surface material that makes up the convection cells that [move the plates](http://www.windows2universe.org/earth/interior/how_plates_move.html) could be made from a less viscous material or something of the like.